# How to loop through columns in two sheets and compare in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

As title says, my latest attempt will compare a column to the other column and iterate through each row. However, I am stuck on how to go to the next columns to iterate through.

```
    Dim i As Long
    Dim s1, s2 As Worksheet
    
    Set s1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set s2= Worksheets("sheet2")
   
    For i = 2 To Rows.Count
        If IsEmpty(s1.Range("B" & i)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If s1.Range("B" & i).Value <> s2.Range("B" & i).Value Then
                s1.Range("B" & i).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Have another loop for `columns.count`?

Comment: What is Star? seems like worksheet but you are not using s1 and S2 which you declare?

Comment: @Aldert my mistake, corrected

Comment: @findwindow range for columns only accepts string, right?

Comment: Is this code in the same workbook as these worksheets? Do you have a list of columns to be checked or will you be checking all columns (except column `A`)? On a side note, when declaring variables, each needs to have a corresponding `As` clause or it will be declared as a variant data type i.e. declare multiple variables in a single line like this: `Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another loop before, but you'll need to change your syntax away from `RangeB` and use `cell` which is numeric for columns. Assuming you're starting with B, and to all columns in sheet... something like this:

```
For C = 2 to sh1.usedrange.columns.count
      For i = 2 To sh1.usedrange.rows.count 
        If IsEmpty(s1.cells(i,c)) Then
            Exit For
        End If
        If s1.cells(i,c).Value <> s2.cells(i,c).Value Then
                s1.cells(i,c).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                
        End If
    Next i
next C
```

I didn't test, but the concept seems like what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

### Highlight Differences

**A Quick Fix (`For...Next`)**

```vb
Sub HighlightDifferences()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Target
    
    ' This is the target worksheet, the worksheet to be highlighted.
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' If you have a nice table (one row of headers, no empty rows or columns),
    ' and it starts with cell 'A1', you can reference the whole range with:
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = tws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = trg.Rows.Count
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = trg.Columns.Count
    ' Clear the previous formats.
    trg.Resize(rCount - 1, cCount - 1).Offset(1, 1).ClearFormats
    
    ' Source
    
    ' This is the source worksheet, the worksheet to be compared to.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Reference the same range as the destination range:
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range(trg.Address)
    
    ' Highlight.
    
    Dim tCell As Range, sCell As Range
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    
    ' By Columns (one column at a time)
    For c = 2 To cCount
        For r = 2 To rCount
            Set tCell = trg.Cells(r, c)
            Set sCell = srg.Cells(r, c)
            If tCell.Value <> sCell.Value Then
                tCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
        Next r
    Next c

'    ' By Rows (one row at a time)
'    For r = 2 To rCount ' ***
'        For c = 2 To cCount ' ***
'            Set tCell = trg.Cells(r, c)
'            Set sCell = srg.Cells(r, c)
'            If tCell.Value = sCell.Value Then
'                tCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
'            End If
'        Next c ' ***
'    Next r ' ***

End Sub
```

**A Quick Fix (`For Each...Next`)**

```vb
Sub HighlightDifferencesForEach()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Target
    
    ' This is the target worksheet, the worksheet to be highlighted.
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ' If you have a nice table (one row of headers, no empty rows or columns),
    ' and it starts with cell 'A1', you can reference the whole range with:
    Dim trg As Range: Set trg = tws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' Reference the range without the first row and the first column.
    Set trg = trg.Resize(trg.Rows.Count - 1, trg.Columns.Count - 1).Offset(1, 1)
    ' Clear the previous formats.
    trg.ClearFormats
    
    ' Source
    
    ' This is the source worksheet, the worksheet to be compared to.
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    ' Highlight.
    
    Dim tCell As Range, sCell As Range
    
    ' By Rows (one row at a time)
    For Each tCell In trg.Cells
        Set sCell = sws.Range(tCell.Address)
        If tCell.Value <> sCell.Value Then
            tCell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        End If
    Next tCell

End Sub
```